# Excel Macro working different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    '
    ' CopyPaste Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+P
    '
        Range("A2:C5").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("A").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("A6:C11").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("B").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("A12:C17").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("C").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("A18:C21").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("D").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End Sub
```

I have trying making a Macro to do a basic task but I can't seem to figure it out, can anyone help please! I'm trying to create a macro that will copy data from one worksheet and place into another worksheet based on specific letter.

For example all "A" item will paste automatically into new worksheet name "A". This I can do with no problem. But, when I want to use the same macro with another row with different no of column is where I have my problem.

I already use recorded macro and then if the row from copy worksheet have been reduced, it will paste wrongly in new worksheet.

Is there any way to solve it?
thanks in advance.

P/S--> the new worksheet will have header in it. so it would be nice if they can paste start from A2 row. Can refer image below for example.

[image]

Comment: If you include your current code (no matter how basic you think it is) and tell us what part of your problem it isn't doing correctly, we will have a chance of telling you what is wrong.

Comment: You should learn how to use variables. This site might help. http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/variables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*See Example / and see comment on the code*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    'Declare your Variables
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim List As Collection
    Dim varValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Set your Sheet name
        Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        'set your auto-filter,  A1
        With Sht.Range("A1")
            .AutoFilter
        End With

        'Set your agent Column range # (1) that you want to filter it
        Set rng = Range(Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).Address)

        'Create a new Collection Object
        Set List = New Collection

        'Fill Collection with Unique Values
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
            List.Add rng.Cells(i, 1), CStr(rng.Cells(i, 1))
        Next i

        'Start looping in through the collection Values
        For Each varValue In List
            'Filter the Autofilter to macth the current Value
            rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=varValue
            'Copy the AutoFiltered Range to new Workbook
            Sht.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
            Worksheets.Add.Paste
            ActiveSheet.Name = Left(varValue, 30)
        Next  ' Loop back

        'Go back to main Sheet and removed filters
        Sht.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Sht.Activate

    End With
End Sub
```

Make sure to have header on your data, see below

[image]